# Ruby on Rails2.3.8: Duplicate entry 'MyString' for key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

So... these MyString entries appear all over my testing database... and I'm not sure why.

I wasn't really a problem, until I needed to set a unique flag on one of the columns that wasn't the ID.

I'm using Factory_girl... So.. I'm not sure what is generating the MyStrings all over the place.
Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your fixtures in test/fixtures. MyString is the default string for your models attributes. They are automatically loaded into your test database.

Comment: If that is the case, better delete fixtures

Comment: Obvious now; not entirely obvious when it defaults to a non-functional state.